# will design be affected in browsers?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

When i am designing my webforms in asp.net3.5 using divs and css, in design the form doesnt look properly aligned(all controls dispersed evrywer), but when i view into browser it shows me well aligned?? how does this happen? and is it going to affect in anyway in future?
here is one of form code

```
    <div id="SRForm">  
        <h1>Room Reservation</h1>


            <div id="SRLeft">
                <ul>
                            <li>Check Availability</li>
                            <li class="status">Select Room</li>
                            <li>Enter Details </li>
                            <li>Review Reservation & Confirm</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

           <div id="RoomType"> 

            <div id="Room1">
               <div class="imgdetails">
                    <img  class="SRimg" src="images/rooms/regular-room.jpg"/>
               </div>
               <div class="roomdetails">
                    <h3>Regular Room</h3>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblroom1" class="lblroom">Available:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblroom2" class="lblroom">no of rooms</asp:Label>
                    <p class="roompara">Well appointed environment friendly rooms with all the facilities available.</p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboroom1" class="cboroom" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div >
                </div>
           </div>

           <div id="Room2">
               <div class="imgdetails">
                    <img  class="SRimg" src="images/rooms/regular-room.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="roomdetails">
                    <h3>Delux Room</h3>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblroom3" runat="server" class="lblroom">Available:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblroom4" runat="server" class="lblroom">no of rooms</asp:Label>

                    <p class="roompara">Well appointed environment friendly rooms with all the facilities available.</p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" class="cboroom" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
                <div class="rate">
                <p class="proom">Charge Per Night:</p>
                <asp:label runat="server" class="lblrate">3000INR</asp:label>
                </div>
           </div>

           <div id="Room3">
               <div class="imgdetails">
                    <img  class="SRimg" src="images/rooms/regular-room.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="roomdetails">
                    <h3>Super-Delux Room</h3>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblroom5" runat="server" class="lblroom">Available:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblroom6" runat="server" class="lblroom">no of rooms</asp:Label>

                    <p class="roompara">Well appointed environment friendly rooms with all the facilities available.</p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" class="cboroom" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div  >
                </div>
           </div>
         </div>     
       </div>


here is css

#SRForm { margin:0; padding:0; width:900px; height:700px;}
#SRForm h1 { text-align:center; font-size:20px; margin: 20px 0; font-weight:bold;}

    #SRLeft      { width:200px; float:left; padding:10px 10px; margin-right:10px; }
    #SRLeft ul   { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; height: 160px;}    
    #SRLeft li   {  margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; float:right;
                        position:relative; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; font-weight:bold;
                        width:180px;}
    #SRLeft li a { text-align:center; display:block; width:180px; float:right;}

    #RoomType    { width: 650px; float:left; height:700px;
                    }

    #Room1 {float:left; width:630px; margin-bottom:10px; height:230px; border:2px solid #FFF; }
    #Room2 {float:left; width:630px; margin-bottom:10px; height:230px;  border:2px solid #FFF;}

    #Room3 {float:left; width:630px; margin-bottom:10px; height:230px;  border:2px solid #FFF;}


    .roompara{ width:380px;font-size:14px;}
    .imgdetails { width:240px; margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;}
    .roomdetails { width:380px; float:left;}
    .roomdetails h3 { font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:380px; margin-top:5px;}
    .lblroom        { margin-top:2px; padding:3px;}
    .cboroom        { width:100px;}
    .rate           { width:630px; margin-left:5px; float:left; height:50px;}
    .SRbtn          { float:right; margin-bottom:10px;}
    .proom          { font-weight:bold;}
    .lblrate        { float:left; position:absolute; margin-left:100px;}


/*----images in Rooms---*/
.SRimg { border:4px solid #eee; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; width:200px; float:left;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Also the rate is not aligning with label charge per night..
Please tell whats the mistake .

Comment: The designer view is only an approximation of what you'll get in the end. Also, different browsers will show different results in some cases (fortunately this gets better with increasing standardization, but it is still the case nevertheless).

Comment: Are you looking at the design through some "Live design view" in Dreamweaver or something similar?

Comment: no  @KyleSevenoaks m not using dreamweaver and i design it through coding not through design view. but when i see in design view its all a mess

Comment: so should think it wont matter my pages ? as i am using asp.net first tym and css too , i want to make sure it wont create a problem for my projct

Comment: Ignore the design view of the program you're using. It is not a standard compliant browser, not even close. ALWAYS test in a real browser (Firefox or Chrome). Never use the design view, it is like you saw, unreliable. If it's messed up in the design view it's not your coding, just the program itself not being able to handle the code. :)

Answer (score -2):

> Please tell whats the mistake.

Your mistake is using asp.net... That was a tongue in cheek reply don't shoot me down.

I'm assuming your using some sort of design view? You're going to run into a whole load of layout problems unless you get it right from the start. I tend to use a reset style sheet, like the one found here - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/